# Sound glitch disappears when changing the RealTek driver version without restarting the computer

Tags: audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio, windows-10-pro

I am under Window 10 Pro (build 19044). Today I started experiencing a glitch when listening to MP3s with generated speech (produced using Amazon Polly). The glitch is a stutter close to the beginning of the file. What's most puzzling is that the glitch disappears almost entirely if I change the version of the RealTek driver, but do not restart the computer. It does not matter whether I change the version from a previous version to the current one or vice versa. The change itself seems to do the trick. The glitch is there again after I restart the computer (again, it does not matter which driver version is active).

What could be going on? What happens when I update the driver without restarting the computer?

Comment: What happens when you restart the computer?   Always advisable after installing a Driver.

Comment: @John As the question states, the glitch comes back.

Comment: I don't know.  Try running all hardware tests and see if that uncovers anything.

Comment: @John What happens when I update the driver **without** restarting the computer? Why does it help?

Comment: At some point, you always have to restart (Windows Updates) so see if there is hardware issue.

Comment: It might be that there are *two* drivers active. Try removing all Realtek audio drivers, do a full reboot, and let PC find new drivers.

Comment: What else have you tried? A different player maybe?

Comment: The Realtek installer uninstalls the current driver before installing the new driver and asks for a reboot in between. What’s happening is that whatever Realtek driver you’re installing is causing the issue apparently. Uninstall the driver all together and reboot or use windows update to see if a working driver will install automatically. Check device manager to see the status. Check the driver name/version before and after.